Импорт слоев с ArcGis сервера на OSM карту
Нашёл много информации о том, как использовать данные из OpenStreetMap в ArcGis, а как сделать наоборот - не нашёл. Использую в JS карту OSM
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(this.map)

И хотелось бы импортировать слои с сервера ArcGis, в котором содержится геодата по инфроструктуре одного конкретного города, но вообще никак не нашел, как это сделать

